# algebraic geometry/ Hartshorne exercises

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $\psi:A \rightarrow B$ be a ring map. Consider the induced map on affine scheme: $f: Y = \operatorname{Spec}B \rightarrow X = \operatorname{Spec}A$. Why is it true that $f^{-1}D(g) = D(\psi(g))$, where $g \in A$?

We know that the pullback of a prime ideal is prime. Thus it is clear that $f^{-1}D(g) \subset D(\psi(g))$. But I cannot see why the other direction holds.

Comment: Thanks! fixed it!

Answer (score 4):

Note that: $f(P)=\psi^{-1}(P)$ for $P\in Spec(B)$. 
Actually, $f^{-1}(D(g)) = D(\psi(g))$ for every $g\in A$, since  $P\in f^{-1}(D(g))$ if and only if $f(P)  \in D(g)$ if and only if $\psi^{-1}(P)  \in D(g)$ if and only if $g\not\in \psi^{-1}(P)$ if and only if $\psi(g)\not\in P$ if and only if $P\in D(\psi(g))$.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is defined by $f(y) = \psi^{-1}(y)$. So

\begin{align}
f^{-1}D(g) &= \{ y \in Y : f(y) \in D(g) \} \\
&= \{ y \in Y : g \notin \psi^{-1}(y) \} \\
&= \{ y \in Y : \psi(g) \notin y \} \\
&= D(\psi(g))
\end{align}